# Personal Wiki, TiddlyWiki5 and MediaWiki Syntax

Tags: plugins, mediawiki, wiki, tiddlywiki

**Background:** I was hoping to run Gollum to run a personal wiki that could just render marked up files I take notes in. But my primary machines are Windows... [so that's not happening](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/356). Running a VM for it is just too much hassle for it's purpose.

**Current Status:** I'd like to give  [TiddyWiki5](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5) a shot primarily because of it's awesome portability. But I'd also like to write/preserve my notes in MediaWiki syntax, to make it easier to port notes or even whole pages over to wikis I commit to.

I have unsuccessfully searched for a plugin to allow mediaWiki syntax.

- The original plugin is outdated and unsupported

**Question:** Does anyone know of a plugin or hack to add mediaWiki syntax support for TW5?

Alternative platform suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Requirements:**

- [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)
- [TiddlyWiki Markdown plugin](http://tiddlywiki.com/markdowndemo.html)
- [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)
- [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)
- [Sublime Text Pandoc](https://github.com/tbfisher/sublimetext-Pandoc)
- [Mediawiker](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker)

---

So after some more research I've decided that for the time being it'd be easiest to just write TiddlyWiki entries in Markdown. Using the [Markdown plugin](http://tiddlywiki.com/markdowndemo.html).

**Then** just convert the markdown files to MediaWiki via [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). Or rather using Pandoc through a [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) plugin.

The settings for [Sublime Text Pandoc](https://github.com/tbfisher/sublimetext-Pandoc) by tbfisher (after installation) are under Preferences => Package Settings => Pandoc => Settings - User.

You also require the Sublime Text [Mediawiker](https://github.com/tosher/Mediawiker) to provide the syntax setting for MediaWiki files.

My current (testing) settings are as follows:

```
{ "user": 
    {   "pandoc-path": "C:/Pandoc/pandoc.exe",

        "transformations": {
            "Markdown (Pandoc)": {
              "scope": { "text.html.mediawiki" : "mediawiki" }
            },

            "MediaWiki" :{
                "new-buffer": 1,
                "scope": { "text.html.markdown" : "markdown" },
                "syntax_file": "Packages/Mediawiker/Mediawiki.tmLanguage",
                "pandoc-arguments": [
                    "--to=mediawiki"
                ]
            },

            "Markdown (GitHub)" : {
                "new-buffer": 1,
                "scope": {
                    "text.html.mediawiki" : "mediawiki+hard_line_breaks",
                    "text.html.markdown" : "markdown" 
                 },
                "syntax_file": "Packages/Markdown/Markdown.tmLanguage",
                "pandoc-arguments": [
                    "--to=markdown_github",
                    "--atx-headers"
                ]
            }
        }    
    }
}
```